# To respond to poor quality questions, is there a canonical reference on Drupal debugging that we can link to?

Tags: discussion, canonical

In response to poor quality questions where the poster clearly has no idea how to ask a question appropriate for a *Stack Exchange* site, it's easy to refer the poster to the *Drupal Answers* FAQ.

However, I have also seen a large number of posts recently where the problem is not that the poster knows how to ask on this type of site but has no idea how to debug Drupal.  For example:

- I enabled a bunch of modules and now something doesn't work.  What can I do?

Is there a canonical (or passable?) debugging reference that we can link to in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

Canonical questions are generic enough question that are used as reference for other questions. They can be created because there is a topic that is referred in other answer, or because there are very similar questions about the same topic that keeps to be asked.
In the second case, the canonical question could be used to close all those similar questions that change for little details.

If the questions are poor quality questions, I would first check they cannot be closed because too ambiguous, vague, or incomplete, or because it is not constructive.

Comment: Well, certainly the questions will probably be closed anyway, but with the goal of helping people understand why they are closed, I think it would be nice to have a link to a debugging resource where clearly that is the issue.  I myself though don't know of a readily accessible introduction to Drupal debugging; all that I have learned has been from bits and pieces here and there.